# Laravel: How to Append additional items to URL query string

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a form that takes two fields

```
SUBURB and STATE
```

and submits the fields to the URL eg.

```
www.mysite.com/?suburb=Manhatten&state=NY
```

In My Laravel Controller I have

```
 if (isset($input['state']) && $input['state'] != '')
        {
            $query = $query->where('state', 'like', '%'. $input['state'].'%');
        }
 if (isset($input['suburb']) && $input['suburb'] != '')
        {
            $query = $query->where('suburb', 'like', '%'. $input['suburb'].'%');
        }
```

I want to allow my users to add additional SUBURBS or STATES so they can get more results eg.

```
www.mysite.com/?suburb= Manhatten OR Brooklyn OR Queens &state= NY OR NJ
```

I don't know how I can setup my form to append a 'OR' to the additional suburbs and how do I setup my controller to look for the additional values?

Comment: You would have to do something custom.  For instance users would have to say `OR`, and then you can use `explode(' OR ', $input['state'])` (then loop through the words and create a long query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add anything extra to your controller for adding `query string`, just add the `query stqing` in the form `action`, for example:

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'search/?suburb=Manhatten/Brooklyn/Queens&state=NY', 'method' => 'post'))
```

Then in your Controller method:

```
if ($state = Input::get('state')) {
    $query = $query->where('state', 'like', '%'. $state .'%');
}

if ($suburb = Input::get('suburb')) {
    $suburbs = explode('/', $suburb);
    $query = $query->where('suburb', 'like', '%'. array_shift($suburbs) .'%');
    if(count($suburbs)) {
        foreach($suburbs as $sub) {
            $query = $query->orWhere('suburb', 'like', '%'. $sub .'%');
        }
    }
}
```